# jMockit's access to a private class

Tags: java, private, inner-classes, jmockit

I have a public class with a private class inside it:

```
public class Out
{
    private class In
    {
        public String afterLogic;

        public In(String parameter)
        {
            this.afterLogic = parameter+"!";
        }
    }
}
```

And wanted to test the In class with jMockit. Something along these lines:

```
@Test
public void OutInTest()
{
    Out outer = new Out();
    Object ob = Deencapsulation.newInnerInstance("In", outer); //LINE X
 }
```

The problema is, in LINE X, when trying to cast ob to In, the In class is not recognized.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the `In` class accessor to public?

Comment: @GETah Unfortunately, I don't feel that this is an option, or this question wouldn't have been posted.

Answer (score 2):

The only constructor in class `In` takes a `String` argument. Therefore, you need to pass the argument value:

```
Object ob = Deencapsulation.newInnerInstance("In", outer, "test");
```

Comment: I don't think this would cause the compile-time issue of the test being able to declare an instance of `In`. Although it probably addresses the run-time issue that had not been hit yet.

Comment: This doesn't work: I cannot cast the ob to In since In is a private class.

Comment: Of course not, since `In` is not visible outside of `Out`... but one can still call methods on `ob` through Reflection. However, the initial idea of testing a private inner class is a bad one; private parts of a class (methods, fields, *or* nested/inner classes) should not be exercised directly in a test; instead, the test should only exercise the non-private methods of the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment one way is to change the access modifier of the inner class from private to public. 
Second way (in case you don't want to make your inner class public), you can test the public method of outer class which is actually calling the inner class methods.

Comment: Default scope would be better than public. And a good point is made here. Effort should be made to test classes as much as possible through the class' exposed API.

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of the inner class to default then make sure that the test is in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches, first as mentioned in other posts to change the scope to public. The second which I support is, to avoid testing private class altogether. Since the tests should be written against testable code or methods of the class and not against default behavior.

Comment: If the inner class is complex then code should be refactored to make it a separate public entity to achieve modularization and easier testing.

Comment: The class is simple but the question is maintained: is it possible to test a private class without the work around of making it public, protected of package-public?